# react-router this is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

This occurs in ReactRouter.js in handleLocationChange:

```
      handleLocationChange: function handleLocationChange(change) {
        this.dispatch(change.path, change.type);
      },
```

This is downstream from my call to

this.context.transitionTo('something');

where 'something' is one of my defined routes. Why would 'this' be undefined?

Here is my component calling the code:

```
var React = require("react");
var Router = require("react-router");
var { Link } = Router;
var Button = require('core-ui').Button;

var AppointmentsHeader = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.PureRenderMixin],
    contextTypes: {
        router: React.PropTypes.func
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log("AppointmentsHeader:render");
        var router = this.context.router;
        // default to hidden
        var displayClassInline = "appointments-hide"; // hide/show this element if the current page is Landing Page

        if (this.props.currentState.get('currentState') === "landingPage")
        {
            displayClassInline = "appointments-block-show";
        }
        return (
            <div className={"appointments-header cv-grid " + displayClassInline}>
                <div className="appointments-title">Appointments</div>
                <Button label="Create Appointment Event" style="primary" onClick={this._onClick}/>
            </div>
        );
    },
    _onClick: function() {
        console.log("AppointmentsHeader 'Create Appointment Event' button clicked");
        var newStatus = this.props.currentState.set('currentState', "CreateAppointment");
        this.props.handleChange(newStatus);
        this.context.transitionTo('createAppointmentsEvent');
    }
});

module.exports = AppointmentsHeader;
```

Comment: Can you provide more context of where that code snippet is coming from? Show us more of your code basically (ideally the entire component).

Comment: That code is inside ReactRouter, here is my component's method making the call:

    _onClick() {
        console.log("AppointmentsHeader 'Create Appointment Event' button clicked");
        var newStatus = this.props.currentState.set('currentState', "CreateAppointment");
        this.props.handleChange(newStatus);
        this.context.transitionTo('createAppointmentsEvent');
    }
});

module.exports = AppointmentsHeader;

Comment: I edited your question with your code, though it seems incorrect to me... shouldn't it be `_onClick: function() { ...` ? Otherwise, you are just running `_onClick` right there and never actually doing anything with it. Please edit the question itself with your full code, if possible.

Comment: I decided that at a minimum the react-router examples are out of date, so I opened an issue on them:

[react router issue](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1161)

Comment: Please, edit your question, do **NOT** put code blocks in comments.

Comment: Debugging the React-Router code, when I call transitionTo, it calls location.push(), which in this case 'push' is a custom function on the location object.

'Push' calls 'notifyChange' and we still have 'this' the entire way so far.

But once we are in 'notifyChange' there is no more 'this'. Hope that helps somebody, I haven't figured it out yet ...

Comment: This is one of the reasons I don’t use react router – the call stack is endless and it’s impossible to debug errors that often occurs. Did you try Backbone router instead?

Comment: I don't actually see you using the `router` anywhere... All you do is define it. Where is the code that actually uses it?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
this.context.transitionTo('createAppointmentsEvent')
```

---

Should be:

```
this.context.router.transitionTo('createAppointmentsEvent');
```

or

```
this.transitionTo('createAppointementsEvent')
```

---

You are accessing the singleton router two different ways in your example:

- The Navigation mixin
- The Router that is injected via the `contextTypes` hash

The API Is very confusing right now because Ryan went down one road (getting rid of mixins entirely) and then decided to "undepricate" the mixins.

Comment: Sorry, but the 'router' is not available on contect, but transitionTo is there.

And the upgrade guide (used to answer other SO questions) specifically states [Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md):   
  
"Without mixins we needed a way for you to get access to these methods. We decided the simplest solution was to stop hiding the router instance and just put the whole thing on context."

Comment: I had not realized I even had the Navigation mixin still in there, that was a mistake according to the upgrade guide, I tried removing it but there is still no 'router' on my context. And after that, trying to access transitionTo on context directly (like the upgrade guide tells) yeilds this error: "Uncaught TypeError: this.context.transitionTo is not a function".

Comment: Ryan advised it should be this.transitionTo and that the upgrade guide is wrong, as are the examples.